# How to transform a CSV file data in Apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I want to transform some field's data in specific rows in csv file.I tried the following .

1).Using csv marshaling and unmarshaling I achieved it ,but the output CSV is not coming in proper order even though I sent list of maps (i.e List) .

following is my program

```
    from("file:E://camelinput//?noop=true")
    .unmarshal(csv)
    .convertBodyTo(List.class)
    .process(new Processor() {

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange msg) throws Exception {
            List<List<String>> data = (List<List<String>>) msg.getIn().getBody();
            List<Map<String,Object>> newdata=new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
            Map<String,Object> map=null;
            for (List<String> line : data) {
                System.out.println(line.size());
                map=new HashMap<String,Object>();

             if("1502873".equals(line.get(3))){
                 line.set(18, "Y");
             }


            // newdata.add(line);
             int count=0;
             for(Object field:line){
                // System.out.println("line.get(count) "+line.get(count));
                 map.put(String.valueOf(count),field);
                 count++;
             }
             newdata.add(map);
            }
            msg.getIn().setBody(newdata);

        }
    })
    .marshal().csv().convertBodyTo(List.class)
```

.to("file:E://camelout").end();

2)And again I tried Using **.split(body())** and trying to process each row(i.e with out using Marshaling I am trying),but it is taking very huge time and getting terminated with some Interrupted exception.

following is the code

```
from("file:E://camelinput//?noop=true")
        .unmarshal(csv)
        .convertBodyTo(List.class)
        .split(body())
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange msg) throws Exception {
            List<String> rec= new ArrayList<String>();
                if("1502873".equals(rec.get(3))){
                     rec.set(18, "Y");
                 }
            String dt=rec.toString().trim().replace("[","").replace("]", "");
                msg.getIn().setBody(dt, String.class);  
    }
        })
    .to("file:E://camelout").end();
```

following is my sample Csv

```
25  STANDARD    N   1435635 415 1087    15904   7       null    36  Cross Mechanical Pencil, Lead and Eraser, 0.5 mm            2   23162   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   828
25  STANDARD    N   1435635 415 1087    15905   8       null    36  Jumbo Ballpoint and Selectip Refill, Medium, Black          4   23163   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   829
25  STANDARD    N   1435635 415 1087    15906   1   3487    null    598 Copier Toner, Cannon            220 23164   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   830
25  STANDARD    N   1435635 415 1087    15907   2   3495    null    823 Envelopes           27  23165   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   831
25  STANDARD    N   1435635 415 1087    15908   3   3513    null    789 Legal Pads, 8 1/2 x 11 3/4"  White"         30  23166   116599  N   832
25  STANDARD    N   1435635 415 1087    15909   4   3577    null    791 Paper Clips         5   23167   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   833
31  STANDARD    N   1574437 415 1087    15910   5       null    36  Clic Stic Pen, Fine, Black          0.72    23168   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   834
31  STANDARD    N   1574437 557 1233    15911   6       null    36  Laser Cards, 50 Note Cards/Envelopes, 4-1/4 inch x 5-1/2 inch, White            21.58   23169   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   835
31  STANDARD    N   1574437 578 1275    15912   1   201 null    32  Keyboard - 101 Key          20.82   23170   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   836
25  STANDARD    N   1574437 147 2033    15913   1   225 null    30  Monitor - 19"           225.39  23171   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   837
1314    STANDARD    N   1502873 22  2199    16287   1   628 null    1   Envoy Deluxe Laptop         822.87  23545   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   838
1314    STANDARD    N   1502873 22  2199    16288   1   151 null    91  Envoy Standard Laptop           1283.44 23546   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   839
7653    STANDARD    N   1502873 22  2199    16289   2   606 null    1   Battery - Extended Life         28  23547   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   840
7652    STANDARD    N   1502873 21  459 16290   1   2157    null    1   Envoy Laptop - Rugged           1525.02 23548   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   841
1314    STANDARD    N   1502873 3   1594    16291   1   251 null    32  RAM - 256MB         51.25   23549   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   842
7654    STANDARD    N   1502873 22  2199    16292   1   606 null    1   Battery - Extended Life         28  23550   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   843
7652    STANDARD    N   1502873 21  459 16293   1   247 null    30  Monitor - 17"           225.39  23551   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   844
1704    STANDARD    N   1502873 41  2200    16294   2   225 null    30  Monitor - 19"           225.39  23552   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   845
7658    STANDARD    N   1502873 21  460 16295   1   201 null    32  Keyboard - 101 Key          20.82   23553   116599  7/7/2015 15:45  N   846
```

I have large Csv files which contains hundreds of thousands of rows.

Comment: When you say "not in proper order" do you mean line order or column order?

Answer (score 2):

I think your solution 1 might be overly complex if you only want to alter values in csv and output it it back in the same order. Just edit fields in the original List and marshall it back to file.

I've made here assumption that your data was actually delimited by tabs rather than random amount of spaces in your example but I've included the CsvDataFormat that I used. Code uses camel-core and camel-csv version 2.15.3.

```java
public void configure() {
    CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat();

    csv.setDelimiter('\t'); // Tabs
    csv.setQuoteDisabled(true); // Otherwise single quotes will be doubled.

    from("file://src/data?fileName=data.csv&noop=true&delay=15m")
        .unmarshal(csv)
        .convertBodyTo(List.class)
        .process(new Processor() {

            @Override
            public void process(Exchange msg) throws Exception {
                List<List<String>> data = (List<List<String>>) msg.getIn().getBody();
                for (List<String> line : data) {
                    // Checks if column two contains text STANDARD 
                    // and alters its value to DELUXE.
                    if ("STANDARD".equals(line.get(1))) {
                        System.out.println("Original:" + line);
                        line.set(1, "DELUXE");
                        System.out.println("After: " + line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).marshal(csv).to("file://src/data?fileName=out.csv")
        .log("done.").end();
}
```

Comment: Hi @jnupponen ,Thank you so much for you reply.I have tried above code it is giving me the following exception.   org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: java.util.Arrays.ArrayList to the required type: java.util.Map with value [25, DELUXE, N, 1435635, 22, 2035, 15902, 5, , null, 36, Classic 0.5 mm Pencil, Black, , , 27, 23160, 116599, 7/7/2015 15:45, N, 826]

Comment: Do you use the exact code above (except for the from() and to() file-definitions)?

Comment: Yes I used as It is .But getting the issue.I think for marshalling It expect the body to be in Map or List of Map's form.

Comment: Which Camel version are you using? My example was written with 2.15.3 and it is working without exceptions.  If you  used some other version I can try to reproduce the error, otherwise I can't say more without seeing exactly what your code looks like.

Comment: Hi @jnupponen.As you told I tried with camel-2.15.2 .It is working fine.Really it is wonderful.Thank you so much for your kind support.

Comment: Hi@jnupponen ,I am trying the same program to read that Csv from HDFS  and write output to hdfs .But it is giving me exception  Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to create Producer for endpoint: Endpoint[hdfs://localhost:8020/user/cloudera/camelout/out.csv]. Reason: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs

Comment: I am defining endpoints  in following way  from("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/cloudera/EBR_HEADERS_116599.csv?splitStrategy=IDLE:1000,BYTES:5")  .to("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/cloudera/camelout/out.csv")

Comment: That problem seems unrelated to your original question. I recommend you create the smallest working example where the problem occurs. If you can't then resolve the problem I'd recommend posting it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are processing single line in single thread. If parallel processing correct for you, try to use ThreadPool.

```
<camel:camelContext id="camelContext">

    .....

    <camel:threadPoolProfile id="customThreadPoolProfile"
                       defaultProfile="true"
                       poolSize="{{split.thread.pool.size}}"
                       maxPoolSize="{{split.thread.max.pool.size}}"
                       maxQueueSize="{{split.thread.max.queue.size}}">
    </camel:threadPoolProfile>
</camel:camelContext>
```

And upgrade split

```
.split(body().tokenize("\n"))
            .streaming()
            .parallelProcessing()
            .executorServiceRef("customThreadPoolProfile")
            .....
.end()
```